# Bind <TextBlock> with collection to create dynamic <run> tags

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, textblock

I am new to Silverlight. I am trying to dynamically load text from the view model and into TextBlock with a specific word highlighted.

Only logic I can think of is to split the string with a word I want to highlight and load each splits with run tag within `<TextBlock></TextBlock>` and change the style of `<run/>` tag you want to highlight.

But I dont know how to do that.

Any code snippet or logic or idea or direction would be helpful.

Comment: How about [this?](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12670/highlight-a-word-in-wpf-richtextbox.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Untested:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="SampleTextBlock" />
```

Set the text block:

```
void SetSampleTextBlock(string[] words)
{
    SampleTextBlock.Inlines.Clear();
    foreach (var word in words) 
    {
       var run = new Run { Text = word };
       if (word == "octopus") 
       {
          run.FontWeight = FontWeights.UltraBold;
       }
       SampleTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
    }
}
```